# Selecting non-aggregate column on 3 table inner join

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, aggregate

I have 3 tables in a standard parent/child kind of "belongs to" relationship in postgres:

> donations --(belong to)--> campaigns --(belong to)--> organisations

Each table has an id column as a primary key, that's used as a foreign key by the child table

If I'm doing a `SELECT` with a `GROUP BY` on the table, I can't select a column from the  related organisations table without an aggregate function, even though there can only be one joining row. I've always worked around this by using `MAX()` since I know there's only one row for the join, eg

```
SELECT 
campaigns.name,
MAX(organisations.name),
SUM(amount)
FROM donations
JOIN campaigns ON campaigns.id = donations."campaignId"
JOIN organisations ON organisations.id = campaigns."organisationId"
GROUP BY campaigns.id;
```

but this feels like quite hacky. Is there a more correct way to do this?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In our case 99% of interaction with this database is managed by Sequelize (a javascript ORM), so camel-casing in our column names allows us to keep the casing in our codebase consistent, and the ORM takes care of quoting the identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by aggregating first and joining to the result of the aggregation:

```
SELECT c.name as campaign_name,
       o.name as organization_name
       d.total_amount
FROM (
  select "campaignId", sum(amount) as total_amount
  from donations
  group by "campaignId"
) d   
  JOIN campaigns c ON c.id = d."campaignId"
  JOIN organisations o ON o.id = c."organisationId"
;
```